# UDP send and receive in kubernetes

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

For my project, I need to send UDP packets to a Kubernetes Pod from an outside cluster. How can I do this?

I am using Kubeadm for creating the cluster. I tried to use nodePort but it seems that my requirement cannot be fulfilled with Nodeport.

Comment: UDP unicast or UDP multicast?

Comment: unicast UDP packet

Comment: @Ranjith Koova, When you wrote "my requirement cannot be fulfilled with Nodeport" what did you exactly mean?. Can you share your requirements?

Comment: UDP server running on kubernet node shall receive udp pcaket from outside cluster

Answer (score 3):

Actually, `NodePort` can be used to expose ports within TCP and UDP protocols. What was the problem in your case?

You can consider using `Nginx Ingress Controller` and creating `ReplicationController` to implement `Nginx ingress` in order to expose your Pods across UDP port as described [Here](https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/tree/master/ingress/controllers/nginx/examples/udp) or you can check this [Link](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/exposing-tcp-udp-services/).

Create [ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/) and specify External port like `<namespace/service name>:<service port>` which you want to access from outside Kubernetes cluster.

Finally, Nginx ingress can be exposed, i.e., using [Kubernetes ExternalIP](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#external-ips).

Comment: i have create node port with  10001:30001/UDP and able to receive the packet at pod if i am sending udp packet with destination port 30001.If i am sending with 10001 (My application is listening on)  packet will not be received.I am looking a configuration where i can use destination port s my application listening port

Answer (score 1):

I am able to find the solution for my requirement.

I have exposed the UDP port for my pod and it works fine.

Example

kubectl expose pod udp-server-deployment-8c8d6d868-c77zx --port=10001 --protocol=UDP  --external-ip=10.1.11.82 --name=udp-server

Thank you all for your support :)